# Driver development: Uninstalling Windows driver

Tags: windows, driver, device-driver, hid

I'm hacking on a virtual HID driver, and for some reason, I'm unable to disable and unable to uninstall the driver in Device Manager.

`devcon.exe remove` also throws an error. Removing the device in Game Controllers dialog in Control Panel tells me to go to Device Manager to remove the device.

Any idea what may be causing this to happen? What might cause Windows to think it's unable to remove the driver?

---

Small update.

Putting the computer to standby allowed me to remove the device.

Removing parts of HID report descriptor (such as the multitouch report, mouse report and keyboard report, neither of which I used) has also fixed the issue.

However, I'd like to understand what exactly went wrong. What has locked down the driver so it cannot be uninstalled?

Comment: What are the exact error messages?

Comment: Errors are generic, on the lines of: "Go to Device Manager to remove this device" and "Unable to uninstall the device". Really, nothing specific is said.

Answer (score 0):

Any process that might be using the driver could be holding it open. One way to see this is to use [Sysinternals' Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and use the "Find" command under the "Handles" menu to search for the name of any DLLs related to the driver.

So, for many drivers shutting down the related processes is easy, but it can be more challenging for one related to the file system. For example, even if you close all maps or mounts on the virtual device, any Windows Explorer processes (including the login shell) could have loaded the driver. Again, PROCEXP is helpful for figuring out some of this...

Answer (score 0):

It's a kernel-mode driver so, you can't "just" disable it. For a driver to be successfully unload, I/O manager must send the clean up request when there are no other handles waiting to be processed or closed.

And if it is a PnP driver, PnP manager must send `IRP_MJ_SHUTDOWN` request to the I/O manager so that I/O manager can start the unloading callback routine.

One way of disabling it by force could be, you can debug the machine's kernel. By doing that you can see which processes are sending requests to this driver and then manually unload the driver (tho it might have severe effects because all of those open handles that hold the driver open must be closed by the I/O manager)